# In Python, use a for-loop and multiplication to create a power function

Tags: python, for-loop, function

I need a function that raises a number to a said power by using multiplication in a for-loop.This is what i have so far:

```
def power(num, power): 
    for x in range(power):
        number = num * num
    return number

print(power(3, 4))
```

Comment: `num` never changes, so `num * num` never changes.  Your function always computes the square of the number.

Answer (score 3):

```
def power(base, exp):
    res = 1
    for _ in range(exp):
        res *= base
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be -

```
def power(num,pow):
  number = 1
  for x in range(pow):
    number=number*num
  return number
```